# Get last value and sum issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the last net_insurance of seach policy and after that sum by type_money
Someone can help me?

This is my table policies

```
  |ID| |POLICY_NUM|  
   1      1234        
   2      5678     
   3      3444    
   4      4577
```

This is my table insurances

```
  |ID|  |POLICY_ID| |NET_INSURANCE|     |TYPE_MONEY|
   1           1           300          1
   2           1           400          2
   3           1           100          1
   4           2           400          1
   5           2           800          2
   6           3           100          1
   7           3           400          2
   8           4           800          2
   9           2           900          1
```

I'm trying to get the last net_insurance of seach policy_id

```
  |ID|  |POLICY_ID|  |LAST_NET_INSURANCE| |TYPE_MONEY|
   3           1           100              1
   9           2           900              1
   7           3           400              2
   8           4           800              2
```

WHAT I REALLY WANT IS THIS

```
  |TYPE_MONEY| |total|
        1        1000  
        2        1200
```

Here is my query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19fb8/6

Please somebody can help me with this?

I will really appreciate help

Comment: Where do you get the total values 1000 and 2000 from? Should the total for TYPE_MONEY be 1200, not 2000?

Comment: My bad, i edit it with 1000 and 1200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT type_money, sum(net_insurance) from insurances
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT max(id) FROM insurances
  GROUP BY policy_id
)
GROUP BY type_money
```

Bear in mind that the input data in your question is different from the one in your fiddle.

Fiddle with the data from the question: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d685/1).

Output with the data from the question:

```
| TYPE_MONEY | TOTAL |
|------------|-------|
|          1 |  1000 |
|          2 |  1200 |
```

Comment: Welcome. I can't wait for the next one :P

Answer (score 0):

Use a groupwise maximum hack, then just add up the results.

```
SELECT insurances.type_money, SUM(insurances.net_insurance)
FROM insurances
LEFT JOIN insurances maxhack
    ON insurances.policy_id = maxhack.policy_id
    AND insurances.id < maxhack.id
WHERE maxhack.id IS NULL
GROUP BY type_money
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: But isn't this the same as taking the max(insurance.id) for each policy? Looks like it will not perform very well on large data sets.

Comment: OP would have to `EXPLAIN` (and try) both to be sure, but in general i don't trust mysql with subqueries, whereas it tends to be okay with simple joins.  (i've done this before with millions-of-rows tables, too.)

Comment: @Eevee i tried your code and i got for type_money(1)=400 and for type_money(2)= 900, seems is not working

Comment: @CarlitosMorales that's because the data in your fiddle is different from the data in your question.  look at your fiddle data carefully; 400 and 900 is correct there.